# Multiprocessing python module for concurrent SQL statements

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am trying to take a series of queries, which run for about 5-7 min a clip, and execute them concurrently using Multiprocessing.  I am not noticing any speedup, it appears the statements are still being run sequentially.

Here is a basic general sample:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<SERVER>; DATABASE=<DATABASE>;Trusted_Connection=True')
cur=conn.cursor()

def query(query_string):
    cur.execute(query_string)
    conn.commit()

insert_data =   [sql_queries.Slow_Query_1(date)
                 for date in next_workday('2015-09-01','2015-09-05')] #next_workday just generates workdays 

pool = Pool(8)
pool.map(query,insert_data)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you importing `multiprocessing.dummy`?  That's explicitly asking _not_ to use multi-processing abilities.

Comment: My (limited) understanding is that the `.dummy` part is just a wrapper around the Threading module, which allows me to use the same API.  I don't think I need true multiprocessing (so bad title on my part), but rather threads, since my constraint is waiting on the DB rather than CPU time.